# Node JS : Validation in migration vs model

Tags: database, model-view-controller, model, migration, database-migration

I added a validation check in model to validate whether the capacity is between 1 to 1000. My question is whether I should make the same validation check at database level using migration or it is not required as when I will try to add a new element with capacity not in range, the model level validation will automatically throw error.
[**Validation in model.js**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjZRH.png)

[**Call to add new element in repository**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM60D.png)

I want to know which among three is the best practice to follow and why -

1. Having validation only at model
2. Having validation only at migration
3. Having check at both